# What order do I watch the Minami-ke series?

Tags: minami-ke

In the Minami-ke franchise, there's:

- Minami-ke
- Minami-ke Betsubara
- Minami-ke Natsuyasumi
- Minami-ke Okaeri
- Minami-ke Okawari
- Minami-ke Omatase; and
- Minami-ke Tadaima

In what order do I watch these series and OVAs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 4 TV series and 3 OVAs in Minami-ke franchise.

### The TV series:

- Minami-ke (Oct 8, 2007 - Dec 31, 2007)
- Minami-ke: Okawari (Jan 7, 2008 - Mar 31, 2008)
- Minami-ke: Okaeri (Jan 5, 2009 - Mar 30, 2009)
- Minami-ke: Tadaima (Jan 6, 2013 - Mar 31, 2013)

### The OVAs:

- Minami-ke: Betsubara (Jun 23, 2009)
- Minami-ke: Omatase (Oct 5, 2012)
- Minami-ke: Natsuyasumi (Aug 6, 2013)

### Timeline (OVAs are in italic):

- Minami-ke (Oct 8, 2007 - Dec 31, 2007)
- Minami-ke: Okawari (Jan 7, 2008 - Mar 31, 2008)
- Minami-ke: Okaeri (Jan 5, 2009 - Mar 30, 2009)
- *Minami-ke: Betsubara (Jun 23, 2009)*
- *Minami-ke: Omatase (Oct 5, 2012)*
- Minami-ke: Tadaima (Jan 6, 2013 - Mar 31, 2013)
- *Minami-ke: Natsuyasumi (Aug 6, 2013)*

Source: http://www.myanimelist.net